# How to programmatically retrieve last modified time of products in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working with WooCommerce (v8.2.0) in WordPress and need to track when updates happen to my products. Specifically, I want to programmatically access the last modified time for each product and to know whether it's been updated in last 24 hours or not. It's updated via the Import Products feature with matching SKUs.

- Products are updated from our POS terminal.
- Updates include changes in quantity.
- Need to set a variable `$isUpdated` to `true` if at least X products are updated.

I've gone through the WooCommerce documentation but haven't found a clear method to retrieve the last modified time for each product. Does WooCommerce offer a built-in feature for this, or is there a recommended approach?

**To clarify the question itself:**

How can I programmatically determine if at least X products have been updated in a given time frame, using the last modified time as a criterion?

Comment: If the process that updates these products is using wp_update_post, then the post_modified column in the wp_posts table will contain the time the post was updated.  If the process is updating the products another way, then it needs to be manually updating this value.  If this post_modified value is being set, you can query for a given time period and check to see if the query returns 15 or more products.

Comment: I will try to do that, but honestly I hope this process is using `wp_update_post`. Thanks! @ChadPhillips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By suggestion made from ChadPhillips within the comments I was able to solve this (because this process of updating these products is using wp_update_post), I did this:

```
function check_if_multiple_products_updated() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, // Retrieve all products
        'fields' => 'ids', // Retrieve only IDs for performance
    );
    $products = get_posts($args);
    $updated_count = 0;
    $time_check = strtotime('-24 hours'); // Check for updates within the last 24 hours

    foreach ($products as $product_id) {
        $last_modified = get_post_modified_time('U', false, $product_id, true);
        if ($last_modified > $time_check) {
            $updated_count++;
        }
    }

    return $updated_count >= 1; // Returns true if 1 or more products were updated in the last 24 hours
}
```

And since this code is used within my custom plugin, I am using this function as follows:

```
// Check if at least 1 products were updated in the last 24 hours
$isUpdated = check_if_multiple_products_updated();
```

then later on:

```
$response[] = $product_data + array("isUpdated"=> $isUpdated);
```